# Redshift - Dropping unused column

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

In Redshift, you appear to not be able to drop a column if there is a view dependent on your table, *regardless* of whether or not your column is referenced.

step 1 - Create table

```
create table codenames
(
  id int identity(0, 1),
  name text,
  code text
)
```

step 2 - Create view

```
create view codenames_names_only
as
select name
from codenames;
```

step 3 - drop unused column

```
alter table codenames
drop column code;
```

At this time, you get the following error:

```
Error: ERROR: cannot drop table x column code because other objects depend on it
Hint: Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

The above works fine in barebones PostgreSQL ([SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/964570))

Thoughts? Ways to get around this without dropping/modifying the views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an acknowledged bug in 2013 and still has not been fixed in 2016..

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=128056